# Problema Callback Hell - NODEJS

Tags: nodejs, shell, exec

Estoy haciendo un trabajo para clase y este requiere que trabaje con NodeJS (Soy muy nuevo en esto) este programa debe ejecutar comandos en Windows.
Se debe pasar un array de comandos en string y recorrerlo para terminar ejecutándolos, si hay algun error quiero que pare el bucle y lance error...

Tengo en la llamada del get que reciba el comando

```
router.get('/exec', (req, res, next) => {
  let execCommands = [
    'sudo -S apt update',
    'no soy un comando',
    'ipconfig /all'
  ];
  execCommands.forEach(c => execShell(c, (err) => {
    if(err){
      console.log("No se pudo ejecutar el comando");
      return; // o break;
    }
  }));
});
```

Para ello tengo implementado una funcion que devuelve un callback y ejecuta exec de child-process:

```
function execShell(command, callback) {
  exec(`echo "manager" | ${command}`, { encoding: 'utf8' }, (err) => {
    if(!err) {
      callback(null)
    }else{
      callback(err)
    }
  });
}
```

La consola de node no enseña nada raro, llega al console.log del error (por cada comando que está mal)... Lo unico que quiero es que al primer fallo el bucle se pare y haga un `res.status(500).send("No se pudo")` o algo así

No se en que estoy equivocandome, ni que pautas debo seguir... estoy intentando entender desde muchos sitios que les pasa el callback hell (que creo que es lo que me pasa) pero no encuentro caso similar al que quiero ... Me gustaria por favor saber que fallo y por qué para aprende, muchas gracias.

Comment: Editando pregunta...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para complementar la excelente respuesta de abulafia, si quisieras ejecutar todos los comandos de manera paralela (como lo estás haciendo ahora), podrías utilizar la versión "promisificada" de exec y tu código quedaría bastante sencillo:

```
const util = require('util');
const exec = util.promisify(require('child_process').exec);

router.get('/exec', (req, res, next) => {
    let commands = [
        'sudo -S apt update',
        'no soy un comando',
        'ipconfig /all'
    ];

    Promise.all( commands.map( command => exec(command) ) )
        .then( results => res.status(200).send("Todo ok"))
        .catch(err => res.status(500).send("No se pudo"))
});
```

`Promise.all` ejecutará TODAS las promesas que le pases y esperará que se resuelvan o fallen. Si cualquiera falla, en lugar de seguir esperando por todas las demás, llama automáticamente al `catch`. Si todas se resuelven, llama al `then`. Creo que esta solución sería más factible en tu caso.

Si necesitas la versión sincrónica:

```
const util = require('util');
const exec = util.promisify(require('child_process').exec);

router.get('/exec', async (req, res, next) => {
    let commands = [
        'sudo -S apt update',
        'no soy un comando',
        'ipconfig /all'
    ];

    for (const cmd of commands) {
        try {
            await exec(cmd);
        }
        catch (error) {
            res.status(500).send("No se pudo")
            return;
        }
    }

    res.status(200).send("Todo ok")
});
```

Comment: ¿qué signirica que si una promesa falla "aborta todas las demás"? yo creo (corrígeme si me equivoco) que lo que ocurre es que en cuanto una falla, el resto de promesas en curso se ignoran, se salta al `catch()` y se da por terminado el Promise.all, pero que las tareas lanzadas mediante exec en realidad seguirán en ejecución hasta que terminen, y que no se pueden cancelar.

Comment: @abulafia estás en lo correcto. Una promesa no puede cancelarse. Con aborta todas las demás, me refería a que no esperará por ninguna de las otras, pero tienes toda la razón en que es confuso. Ya edité esa parte.

Comment: puedes usar [Promise.allSettled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled)

Comment: @JackNavaRow `allSettled` va a ejecutar el then incluso cuando uno de los comandos falle. Eso NO es lo que se quiere.

Comment: Gracias por todo, arreglado conlo que habeis dicho, un abrazo

Answer (score 4):

El término *callback hell* se refiere a la estructura del código que aparece  cuando tienes llamadas asíncronas, implementadas mediante callbacks, que dependen unas de otras (es decir, que para ejecutar la siguiente, necesitas el resultado de la anterior). Pero ya que el resultado de la anterior se recibe como parámetro de un callback, eso te obliga a hacer la llamada a la siguiente desde dentro de ese callback. Eso causa que los callbacks se vayan anidando unos dentro de otros, y el código se vaya indentando hacia la derecha con cada nueva llamada, haciéndose ilegible.

Tu problema es que tal como lo tienes planteado, al ser las llamadas asíncronas, el bucle `forEach()` está lanzando todos los comandos del shell "a la vez", con la intención de que se ejecuten en paralelo. A medida que cada comando va terminando (y cada uno puede tardar un tiempo diferente), se van ejecutando  los callbacks en los que se recibirá la respuesta.

Por tanto no tiene sentido la petición de "ante el primer error salir del bucle". En realidad del bucle ya has salido mucho antes de recibir ningún tipo de error, pues el bucle completo se limita a "lanzar" todos los comandos, pero no espera a que cada uno termine antes de lanzar el siguiente.

Por lo mismo tampoco tiene mucho sentido "parar ante el primer error", pues es posible que el primer comando en terminar no sea el primero que has lanzado. Quizás fue el último, pero terminó antes precisamente debido al error. Entonces ¿por qué querrías abortar la ejecución de los dos primeros que a lo mejor fue exitosa?

Repiensa un poco lo que necesitas. Es posible que lo que necesites al final sea convertir el código asíncrono en síncrono. Es decir, que cada comando del shell se ejecute y tu tarea no prosiga hasta que ese comando haya terminado, y en caso de haber terminado con éxito pase al siguiente y en caso de haber terminado con error que aborte el bucle. Si es eso lo que necesitas, entonces sí tendrías un verdadero callback-hell, pues estarías introduciendo dependencias entre las tareas asíncronas, forzando a que cada una solo pueda comenzar cuando la anterior haya terminado.

En este caso la solución moderna que evita el callback-hell y devuelve la legibilidad al código sería usar Promesas y async/await.

### Implementación con promesas y async/await

Podemos modificar tu función `execShell()` para que en lugar de usar callbacks como parámetro, cree y retorne una promesa:

```js
function execShell(command) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    exec(`echo "manager" | ${command}`, { encoding: 'utf8' }, (err) => {
        if(!err) {
          resolve(null)
        }else{
          reject(new Error(err));
        }
      });
    });
}
```

Observa que esta función crea un objeto de tipo `Promise()` y lo retorna inmediatamente. Este objeto recibe como único parámetro una función que se va a ejecutar cuando la promesa es creada. Es desde dentro de esa función desde la que llamamos a `exec()` ya que esa ejecución es asíncrona, puede tardar en hacerse, pero aún así la promesa ya estará creada y será retornada inmediatamente. Cuando el comando `exec()` haya finalizado, llamará al callback que le hemos pasado como tercer parámetro, y desde dentro de ese callback resolvemos la promesa o la rechazamos, según el valor recibido en `err`.

Esto sigue siendo una ejecución asíncrona, pero permite que quien llame a `execShell()` pueda esperar fácilmente hasta que la promesa se haya resuelto, antes de proseguir, si la invoca así:

```js
  await execShell(comando)
```

Fijate que no es necesario ya pasar callbacks. Lo que hace await es pausar la ejecución de esta tarea hasta que la promesa resuelta por execShell() se haya resuelto, y entonces proseguirá. La promesa se resuelve cuando desde su código invoque `resolve()` lo que ocurrirá cuando el comando enviado a `exec()` haya finalizado.

¿Y qué pasa si en vez de `resolve()` la promesa termina resolviéndose con un `reject()` debido a que `exec()` retornó error? En ese caso `await` generará una excepción. Eso nos permite meter el `await execShell()` en un bloque try/catch para capturar ese error y hacer lo que se quiera con él, en este caso por ejemplo salir del bucle.

Así que tu función que llama en bucle a `execCommand()` podría quedar así. Eso sí, ahora estás obligado a declarar esa función como `async`, espero que no sea un problema en tu caso:

```
async function demo() {
    const execCommands = [
      'sudo -S apt update',
      'no soy un comando',
      'ipconfig /all'
    ];
    for (const cmd of execCommands) {
        try {
            await execShell(cmd);
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.log("No se pudo ejecutar el comando", error.message);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Para poder hacer una demo completa "funcional", voy a proporcionar un código para la función `exec()` que emule su interfaz. Podría ser así:

```js
function exec(cmd, opts, callback) {
    console.log("Ejecutando ", cmd);
    if (cmd.includes("soy")) { callback ("No es un comando valido")}
    else { callback(); }
}
```

#### Demo funcional

Puedes probar a ejecutarla.

```js
function exec(cmd, opts, callback) {
    console.log("Ejecutando ", cmd);
    if (cmd.includes("soy")) { callback ("No es un comando valido")}
    else { callback(); }
}

function execShell(command) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    exec(`echo "manager" | ${command}`, { encoding: 'utf8' }, (err) => {
        if(!err) {
          resolve(null)
        }else{
          reject(new Error(err));
        }
      });
    });
}

async function demo() {
    const execCommands = [
      'sudo -S apt update',
      'no soy un comando',
      'ipconfig /all'
    ];
    for (const cmd of execCommands) {
        try {
            await execShell(cmd);
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.log("No se pudo ejecutar el comando.", error.message);
            break;
        }
    }
}

demo();
```

Comment: Entonces tendre que probar con promesas porque quiero que la ejecucion de los comandos pese a estar en el bucle sea sincrono (que ejecute uno y si todo fue ok el siguiente). Gracias

Comment: Pues en un momento te pongo código de cómo sería la idea (a ver si así me quito el voto negativo... :-))

Comment: @Alex esta opcion es valida, que quieres que al finalizar se ejecute el siguiente script?

Comment: @abulafia, podrias hacer dentro del catch un throw error, esto cuando express lo vea lo resolvera como error 500 , se que es clase de escuela, y tu como profe no veo el mensaje "esto es un error de seguridad"